# How to multiplying data from input to data in database using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to multiply data from input (quantity) to data in the database (price) and show the result (total price) using AJAX

I expected when I change the quantity:

1. page automatically refresh and show the result (total price) of multiplying the quantity
2. data (total price) in the database too will be updated

What I got :

1. when I change data (quantity) page refreshed but data (quantity) will return to the previous value, and the result (total price) didn't change too
2. data (total price) not updated in database

When it fails, I try not using ajax and manually refresh the page but the result (total price) still not change, then I try to check in the console and see quantity data is changing but somehow it's not multiplying to (price) in data base

cart.php

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    global $pid;
?>
<!--index.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map Store</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fc847822ba.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Map Store</a>

      <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- Navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="index.php">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Category</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="cart.php">Checkout</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="cart.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-white"> <span id="cart-item" class="badge badge-danger"></span></i></a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div style="display: <?php if(isset($_SESSION['showAlert'])){echo $_SESSION['showAlert'];} else {echo'none';} unset($_SESSION['showAlert']);  ?>" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-3">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                  <strong><?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){echo $_SESSION['message'];} unset($_SESSION['showAlert']);  ?></strong> 
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive mt-2">
                    <table class="table table-boarded table-stripped text-center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">
                                <h4 class="test-center text-info m-0"> Products in your cart</h4>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Total Price</th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="action.php?clear=all" class="badge-danger badge p-2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?');"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Clear cart</a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                require 'config.php';
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart");
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                                $grand_total = 0;

                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):

                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td type="hidden"><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="pid" class="pid"  value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                                <td><img src="<?= $row['product_image'] ?>" width="50"> </td>
                                <td><?=  $row['product_name']?></td>
                                <td><?= number_format ($row['product_price'],2); ?> </td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="pprice" class="pprice" value="<?= $row['product_price']?>" >
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="qty" min="1" class="form-control itemQty" value="<?= $row['qty'] ?>" style="width: 75px;"></td>
                                <td><?= number_format ($row['total_price'],2 ); ?></td>

                                <td>
                                    <a href="action.php?remove=<?= $row['id'] ?>" class="text-danger lead" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?');"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $grand_total +=$row['total_price']; ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>&nbsp;Continue Shopping</a>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2"><b>Grand Total :</b></td>
                            <td><?= number_format ($grand_total,2); ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="checkout_1.php" class="btn btn-info <?= ($grand_total>1)?"":"disabled"; ?>"><i class="far fa-credit-card">&nbsp;</i>Checkout</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>            
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
                $(".itemQty").on('change', function(){
                    var $el     = $(this).closest('tr');

                    var pid     = $el.find(".pid").val();
                    var pprice  = $el.find(".pprice").val();
                    var qty     = $el.find(".itemQty").val();
                    //console.log(qty);
                    location.reload(true);


                    $.ajax({
                        url     : 'action_1.php',
                        method  : 'post',
                        cache   : false,
                        data    : {qty:qty,pid:pid,pprice:pprice},
                        success : function(response){

                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
                });


        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

action_1.php

```php
    <!--action.php-->
    <?php

        session_start(); 
        require 'config.php';



    if(isset($_POST['qty'])) {
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $pid = $_POST['id'];
        $pprice = $_POST['pprice'];

        $tprice = $qty*$pprice;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE cart SET qty=?, total_price=? WHERE id=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("isi",$qty,$tprice,$pid);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['action']) == 'order') {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $products = $_POST['products'];
        $grand_total = $_POST['grand_total'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $pmode = $_POST['pmode'];

        $data = '';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (name,email,phone,address,pmode,products,amount_paid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssss",$name,$email,$phone,$address,$pmode,$products,$grand_total);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM cart");
        $stmt->execute();


        echo 'Thank You';
    }
    ?>
```

I expected when I change the quantity:
1. page automatically refresh and show the result (total price) of multiplying the quantity 
2. data (total price) in the database too will be updated

What I got :
1. when I change data (quantity) page refreshed but data (quantity) will return to the previous value and the result (total price) didn't change too
2. data (total price) not updated in database

Comment: This is a very specific question regarding your also very specific code. The first thing that I see is that you are reloading the page with `location.reload(true)` before your ajax call, which will most likely prevent your ajax from running.

Comment: I try to put location.reload(true) at success function response but the output is same

Comment: You should then first validate that your POST data is being received ok in the server: use `print_r($_POST)` under your `require 'config.php';` line and tell us what you get. Also, store your `$stmt->execute();` in a variable like this `$result = $stmt->execute();` and do `print_r($result)` to debug if the sql command got executed or not.

Comment: Thnx. I already try your advice,  there's nothing change when I try your first advice. For second and later I try and nothing changes. Seems theres something wrong I MySQL command and cause it's not executed

Comment: Hi @Toraz Bellial, my 2nd advice was not meant to fix it but to get more info about the SQL code being executed. Do you your data being sent correctly (`print_r($POST)`)? What do you see when `print_r($result)` gets executed?

Comment: Thnx, you so much for your advice. The problem already solved and the reason typo, $pid = $_POST['id']; in action_1.php should be 'pid' not 'id'. Once again thnx u and sorry trouble u.

Comment: Great, glad that you found the issue @Torax Bellial; `print_r(...)` is really useful when debugging.